# Filter out values higher and lower - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am receiving data from some sensors. But last week there was some issues and that led to that some sensors sent wrong and abnormal values. E.g. + 678 degrees celsius and - 456 degree celsius.

But this occured just a few times a day, and a lot of normal data came in as well. So i cant just filter out the days, i want to filter out just the wrong values.

I tried to make a custom column, where i had an if statement to set the wrong values to 1 and det normal to 0 and then just remove all the rows with 1. But i am only receiving 0, when i know there is some rows that suppose to be 1.

This is my if statement:

```
if [Sensor Type] = "Temperature" and [SensorValue] > 60 and [SensorValue] < 0 then 1
else if [Sensor Type] ="Humidity" and [SensorValue] > 90 and [SensorValue] < 1 then 1 
else if [Sensor Type] = "CO2" and [SensorValue] > 1200 and [SensorValue] < 1 then 1
else if [Sensor Type] = "Openings" and [SensorValue] > 4000 and [SensorValue] < 1 then 1
else 0
```

In this column am i only getting 0.

Can anyone help me with this or do you have any other way to filter out the wrong values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A temperature can't be greater than 60 *AND* less than 0 at the same time. To be correct your check should be `[Sensor Type] = "Temperature" and ([SensorValue] > 60 or [SensorValue] < 0)`, so something like this:

```
if [Sensor Type] = "Temperature" and ([SensorValue] > 60 or [SensorValue] < 0) then 1
else if [Sensor Type] ="Humidity" and ([SensorValue] > 90 or [SensorValue] < 1) then 1 
else if [Sensor Type] = "CO2" and ([SensorValue] > 1200 or [SensorValue] < 1) then 1
else if [Sensor Type] = "Openings" and ([SensorValue] > 4000 or [SensorValue] < 1) then 1
else 0
```

It may be easier to understand, if you do the opposite:

```
if [Sensor Type] = "Temperature" and [SensorValue] > 60  then 0
else if [Sensor Type] = "Temperature" and [SensorValue] < 0 then 0
else if [Sensor Type] ="Humidity" and [SensorValue] > 90 then 0
else if [Sensor Type] ="Humidity" and [SensorValue] < 1 then 0 
else if [Sensor Type] = "CO2" and [SensorValue] > 1200 then 0
else if [Sensor Type] = "CO2" and [SensorValue] < 1 then 0
else if [Sensor Type] = "Openings" and [SensorValue] > 4000 then 0
else if [Sensor Type] = "Openings" and [SensorValue] < 1 then 0
else 1
```